# How to count a word covering both triple and double word cells?

Tags: scrabble

In my game I managed to produce a word `womanizers` which covers both "double word" and "triple word" squares. Should I myltiply final count by 2, 3 or 6?

Comment: It's impossible to land a word on both a double word and a triple word in standard scrabble. Possibly a double letter and a triple word? In which case, you would be multiplying that letter by 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the rules](https://scrabble.hasbro.com/en-us/rules):

> Premium Word Squares: The score for an entire word is doubled when one
>   of its letters is placed on a pink square: it is tripled when one of
>   its letters is placed on a red square. Include premiums for double or
>   triple letter values, if any, before doubling or tripling the word
>   score. **If a word is formed that covers two premium word squares, the
>   score is doubled and then re-doubled (4 times the letter count), or
>   tripled and then re-tripled (9 times the letter count).*** NOTE: the
>   center square is a pink square, which doubles the score for the first
>   word.

Which means:

- If the word (or the extention of a word) covers two double word squares, the value of the word counts 4 times.
- If the word (or the extention of a word) covers two tripple word squares, the value of the word counts 9 times.

**Note 1**: The 2x and 3x only count once, in the turn they are covered.

**Note 2**: On the standard board, there are no 2x and 3x fields in a single row or column, so it is not possible to have a 2x and a 3x in the same word. And yes the start field (2xword) is in line with (3xword) but there are 8 tiles needed so it is not possible in a single turn. If there was a board containing these fields it would be logical to asume that they count for 6. (

Comment: I managed to make this word in two turns)

Comment: @xuesheng : then note as well that the double word square covered in the first turn no longer counts as a special square on your second turn. If you played, say, `woman` on the starting double word square (and scored double) and then on your subsequent turn added `izers` to it, reaching the triple word square, you only get the triple -- the previously-covered double word square doesn't count. There is no way to cover both the starting center square and one of the triple word squares in that single starting turn, and there are no other double word squares in line with any triple word squares.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson Thanks for clarification! Now it's all clear!